# Encode and Decode Byte Array using Lz4net

Tags: c#, lz4

Is this the proper way to `Encode` and `Decode` a byte array using `Lz4net`?

```
byte[] filedata = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Test.txt");
byte[] encodedfileData = LZ4.LZ4Codec.Encode(filedata, 0, filedata.Length);
byte[] decodedfileData = LZ4.LZ4Codec.Decode(encodedfileData, 0, encodedfileData.Length, 0);
```

`decodedfileData` returns 0 bytes

I have gone through [LZ4 github](https://github.com/MiloszKrajewski/lz4net), but I am not getting any idea what's wrong. So what is the proper way to `Encode` and `Decode` a byte array using `LZ4`?

Comment: do you want only to compress it ? Why you didn't use 'wrap' ?

Comment: @farbiondriven I am working image transfer program with larger byte array. I dnt know wrap is compatible with large byte array byte

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
byte[] filedata     =  File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Test.txt");
byte[] compressed   =  LZ4.LZ4Codec.Wrap(in);
byte[] uncompressed =  LZ4.LZ4Codec.UnWrap(compressed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the unpacked size (**`filedata.Length`**) as the last parameter:

```
byte[] decodedfileData = LZ4.LZ4Codec.Decode(
    encodedfileData, 
    0, 
    encodedfileData.Length, 
    filedata.Length);
```